# How to reset venv's activate script?

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

I'm using the venv that comes with python 3.

I accidentally typed `script bin/activate` instead of `source`, which edited the activate script. Since it was in my gitignore, I can't restore it through git. I tried copying [this activate script](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/venv/scripts/posix/activate) from the souce, but running it gives a prompt __VENV_PROMPT__... instead of (folder)... so I'm worried that other things might be wrong too.

How can I fix my activate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using python3 venv run the venv creation command again.

```
python -m venv env_name
```

where env_name is path to virtualenv you created, but before doing this, exit current running the terminal or command prompt